# Flask-SQLAlchemy: '"{0}" is not a valid field for {1}.'.format(key, obj))

Tags: python, api, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm trying to create an API with Flask and SQLAlchemy, my function add_user is working perfectly, get_all users too, but i have some issues on my get users (return a specific user ) selected by email (mail is my primary key).

```
class User(db.Model):
    #id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    badgenum = db.Column(db.String(30))
    mail = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String(30))
    admin = db.Column(db.String(30))
    #borrowed = db.relationship('Borrowing', backref='user', lazy=True)

def __init__(self, name, badgenum, mail, status, admin):
    self.name = name
    self.badgenum = badgenum
    self.mail = mail
    self.status = status
    self.admin = admin


class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'badgenum', 'mail', 'status', 'admin')
user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)
```

then , my function that causes problems:

```
@app.route("/users/<mail>", methods=["GET"])
def user_detail(mail):
    user = User.query.filter(User.mail == mail).first()
    return user_schema.jsonify(user.name)
```

I test my API with Postman, i added 2 new users to my database, then when i try the last function i have this error:

> line 834, in __filter_fields
>       '"{0}" is not a valid field for {1}.'.format(key, obj)) AttributeError: "status" is not a valid field for username1.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
    user = User.query.filter_by(mail=mail).first()
    return user_schema.jsonify(user)
```

Comment: actually both the code works,

        `user = User.query.filter(User.mail == mail).first()`
or

        `user = User.query.filter_by(mail=mail).first()`

. while returning the result, we can say like .

        `return user_schema.jsonify(user)`